# I want to pass the screen in onTap

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to pass screens which i have built in this navigator onTap

```
onTap: () => Navigator.push(context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builstrong textder: (context) => QuestionPaperScreen()))
```

There is a QuestionPaperScreen() and I want to pass here a screen which is received as a variable on Function call
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

In QuestionPaperScreen you can define and variable and mark it as required and pass it from this screen

```dart
class QuestionPaperScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final String routeName;
  const QuestionPaperScreen({Key? key, required this.routeName}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Then on tap you can use

```
 onTap: (){
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_)=>QuestionPaperScreen(routeName:'/routeNameHere')));//pass the route name that you received from a function here
  },
```